# Custom HTML5 audio API: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, audio

I'm trying to create my own custom audio HTML5 controls. I read this [tutorial](http://www.alexkatz.me/html5-audio/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-javascript/) which also has a working example.

I'm working locally and I'm getting the following error once I click on the element:

```
this is clicked: <button class=​"play-button audio-button icon icon-loudspeaker" data-audio-button>​…​</button>​
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I would like to know what I'm missing as the tutorial example does work and I modified it slightly.

HTML5:

```
<button class="play-button audio-button icon icon-loudspeaker" data-audio-button></button>
    <audio controls="controls" preload="true" data-music>
        <source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.mp3" type="audio/ogg" />
        <source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.ogg" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
```

jQuery:

```
(function($){
    'use strict';

    // variable to store HTML5 audio element
    var music = $('[data-music]');
    var audioButton = $('[data-audio-button]');

    audioButton.on('click', function(){

        console.log('this is clicked:', this);

        if (music.paused) {
            music.play();
            audioButton.removeClass('icon-loudspeaker');
            audioButton.addClass('icon-play-button');
        } else {
            music.pause();
            audioButton.removeClass('icon-play-button');
            audioButton.addClass('icon-close');
        }
    });


}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Try `var music = $('[data-music]')[0];`

Comment: @Brad It solved the undefined issue. Could you explain why so I can understand the issue??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var music = $('[data-music]');
```

When you use jQuery to find an element, it actually finds an array of elements and wraps them so that you can use jQuery-specific functions on them.  Since you want the element itself (and only one element), you can specify the first array index to retrieve it.

```
var music = $('[data-music'])[0];
```

Then, you can use the element like any other normal element.

See also:  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/